# Change M.mysite.com to WWW.mysite.com in a URL

Tags: php

I use a javascript function on mobile page to redirect users to main page(pc). So i want to change the url! Change M.MYSITE.COM/somepath/page.HTML to WWW.MYSITE.COM/somepath/page.HTML

Mobie URL

```
 m.mysite.com/pics/en/?wallpaper/super-man_w39.html
```

To main URL

```
 www.mysite.com/pics/en/?wallpaper/super-man_w39.html
```

Is there any way using PHP? I tried using parse url but i failed! help me? any way?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect or you think you can change URL to whatever?

Comment: no i use same script in both mobile and pc site..so if some pc user went to mobile page,i want to redirect him back to extract pc page of that mobile page !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your url will always be that format, you can use this:

```
var url = "m.mysite.com/pics/en/?wallpaper/super-man_w39.html";
var r = "www." + url.substr(2, (url.length - 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework doing exactly the mobile redirection (and the redirect back to the normal website).

User choice is saved in cookies or local storage, the configuration options are very flexible:

https://github.com/sebarmeli/JS-Redirection-Mobile-Site

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

```
<?
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']===strtolower("m.mysite.com")){
header("location: www.mysite.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit();
}
?>
```

you really should do it with nginx or apache conf if it's for all items in subdomain.